# Creating array/object definition using other array/object items

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to create an array where the items/Definition of the array are depended on another array.
Like I have an dynamic array

```
arrayDef =[ { title:'item1',validtors:'..',....}
          , { title:'item2',validtors:'..',....}
          ,..]
```

Now I need to create an array using title from the dynamic array. Later I need to append to same array for new row.
Example,

```
arrayData=[ {item1:'',item2:'',...} ]
```

arrayDef is being created by user dynamically where they can add column headers and validations. arrayData is to be created using that. I have tried few methods like map, but is looking into most optimal and time saving approach.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and wrap result of reduce in an array.

```js
const arrayDef = [
  { title: "item1", validtors: ".." },
  { title: "item2", validtors: ".." },
];

let arrayData = [
  arrayDef.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const { title } = curr;
    acc[title] = "";
    return acc;
  }, {}),
];

console.log(arrayData);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best approach is to use something like reduce.

```
arrayDef.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc[item.title] = '';
    return acc;
}, {})
```